# Need to add redirect as well as not trigger the script on clicking the buy button

Tags: javascript, redirect

this is my script that works the way i need it to right now for the most part:

```
<script>
  window.onbeforeunload = function(){   
  return 'Are you seriously leaving? I thought you were really serious 
</script>
```

I now need to add a redirect to url on to this script, and i also do not want the script to trigger at all outside of somebody leaving the page, or closing the window.  The script should never trigger if you click say for instance, the buy button.  How exactly would i edit this script to add this extra functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Add window.open method before leaving message. But this wont work if user has pop up disabled.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
window.open('your url')   
return 'Are you seriously leaving? I thought you were really serious
```